# Simplify Boolean Expression Help

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a question: is this true the way I solve it?

$$\begin{align*}
xyz&+xyz'+xy'z+xy'z'+x'y'z+x'yz'\\
&= xy+xy'+x'y'z+x'yz'\\
&= x(y+y')+x'y'z+x'yz'\\
&= x+x'y'z+x'yz'\\
&= x+x'z'z\\
&=x
\end{align*}$$

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Use a truth table and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly can’t be right, because the original expression is true when $x$ and $y$ are false and $z$ is true, and the final expression is not.

You were doing fine up through $x+x'y'z+x'yz'$, but the next step doesn’t work. However,

$$\begin{align*}
x+x'y'z+x'yz'&=x+x'(y'z+yz')\\
&=\big(x+x(y'z+yz')\big)+x'(y'z+yz')\\
&=x+\big(x(y'z+yz')+x'(y'z+yz')\big)\\
&=x+y'z+yz'\;,
\end{align*}$$

and you’re not going to get it any simpler than that.

Comment: thx for the correction but I have a question; is it possible to solve the problem with consensus?

Comment: @Donny: For the step where you went wrong: no, because in the terms $x'y'z$ and $x'yz'$ both the literal $y$ and the literal $z$ appear in opposition, and in that case you can’t form a consensus term. You can form a consensus term only when there is exactly one literal that appears in opposition.

Comment: I meant using the consensus from the start. Is it possible? Or is it okay to simplify first using absorption then consensus? Sorry, I'm a complete beginner to this and my teacher doesn't teach well...

Comment: @Donny: It’s okay to use any legitimate identity at any stage in the computation.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't quiet understand about your step of solving you posted before; why there is x(y'z+yz')+x'(y'z+yz')? is it from an identity?

Comment: @Donny: I used absorption in reverse: $x=x+x(y'z+yz')$. I just added some parentheses to make that a little clearer.

Comment: Ah i get it now. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Donny: You’re welcome.

Comment: Oh and one last thing, could I use consensus for x' + xy' so that it will be y'?

Comment: @Donny: No, because $x'+xy'$ is true when $x$ is false and $y$ is true, but $y'$ isn’t. However, $$x'+xy'=(x'+x'y')+xy'=x'+(x'+x)y'=x'+y'\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

The following truth-table indicates that you are indeed doing something wrong:

```
 x | y | z | xyz | xyz' | xy'z | xy'z' | x'y'z | x'yz' | result | equal to x
---|---|---|-----|------|------|-------|-------|-------|--------|------------
 0 | 0 | 0 |  0  |  0   |  0   |  0    |   0   |   0   |   0    |     yes
 0 | 0 | 1 |  0  |  0   |  0   |  0    |   1   |   0   |   1    |     no
 0 | 1 | 0 |  0  |  0   |  0   |  0    |   0   |   1   |   1    |     no
 0 | 1 | 1 |  0  |  0   |  0   |  0    |   0   |   0   |   0    |     yes
 1 | 0 | 0 |  0  |  0   |  0   |  1    |   0   |   0   |   1    |     yes
 1 | 0 | 1 |  0  |  0   |  1   |  0    |   0   |   0   |   1    |     yes
 1 | 1 | 0 |  0  |  1   |  0   |  0    |   0   |   0   |   1    |     yes
 1 | 1 | 1 |  1  |  0   |  0   |  0    |   0   |   0   |   1    |     yes
```

---

An alternative solution:

This expression is an OR of $6$ out of $8$ possible ANDs.

So you can take the negation of an OR of the remaining $2$ ANDs.

The remaining $2$ ANDs are $x'yz$ and $x'y'z'$.

The negation of their OR is $(x'yz+x'y'z')'$.

Using de-morgan law, it is equivalent to $(x+y'+z')(x+y+z)$.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner to these boolean things but thanks for the comment. I will try to master it

Comment: @DonnyAvaris: You're welcome :)